# Cutting up Image IllegalArgumentException for createWritableChild

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

So I'm hoping somebody will be able to help me out with this. I am writing a Jigsaw Puzzle game for my Computer Graphics class and I have run into a bit of a snag while trying to cut up my image into pieces. I believe the problem lies with the createWritableChild, but truthfully this error message isnt exactly clear so I am not certain. This is my error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Raster ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 45 height = 45 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 137 has minX or minY not equal to zero: 45 0
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.(Unknown Source)
    at JigsawPuzzle.runPuzzleCreate(JigsawPuzzle.java:106)
    at JigsawPuzzle.gameBoardCreate(JigsawPuzzle.java:137)
    at JigsawPuzzle$3.paintComponent(JigsawPuzzle.java:65)

Here is my code that throws the error:

```
//Cuts up the given Image and creates the Puzzle and its Pieces.
public Puzzle runPuzzleCreate(BufferedImage p){
    int pieceCount = 150;
    int pieceSize = 45;
    Piece[] pieces = new Piece[pieceCount];
    Piece[] scaled = new Piece[pieceCount];
    Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle(p, pieces, scaled);
    ColorModel cm = p.getColorModel();
    boolean premult = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = p.copyData(null);
    Posn pos = new Posn(0, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < pieceCount; i++){
        if(pos.xPos <= 555){
            WritableRaster childRaster = 
                raster.createWritableChild(pos.xPos, pos.yPos,
                        pieceSize, pieceSize,
                        pos.xPos, pos.yPos,
                        null);
            BufferedImage pieceImage = new BufferedImage(cm, childRaster,
                    premult, null);
            Piece piece = new Piece(pieceImage, pos);
            pieces[i] = piece;
            scaled[i] = piece;
            pos.xPos += pieceSize;
        } else if (pos.yPos <= 450){
            pos.yPos += pieceSize;
            pos.xPos = 0;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return puzzle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shame this exception is not documented, but looking at its message and the source code of BufferedImage, it seems you need to pass 0 for the 5th or sixth argument (or both) of the `raster.createWritableChild()` method call.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked great. This throws me off though because the documentation for createWritableChild() says this:             To create a new WritableRaster that contains a subregion of the current WritableRaster, but shares its coordinate system and bands, this method should be called with childMinX equal to parentX, childMinY equal to parentY, and bandList equal to null.                                                                                           So I guess I misunderstood this statement.